# Java and For Loops

Tags: java

I am trying to write a short program that finds the multiples between two numbers not including those numbers.

```
import java.util.*;
  public class MinilabLoops
   {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
      int numFirst = kb.nextInt();
      int numSecond = kb.nextInt();

      System.out.println("\nThis program will generate numbers BETWEEN\n" + numFirst + " and " + numSecond + " that are divisible by a certain number.");

      System.out.print("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by: ");
    int numDivisible = kb.nextInt();

      while (numDivisible == 0)
      {
          System.out.println("You cannot divide by 0, Please try again. ");
        numDivisible  =  kb.nextInt();
      }

      if (numFirst  <= numSecond)
          {
              for (int x = numFirst  ; x != numSecond ; x++)
                  if (x % numDivisible == 0)
                    System.out.println(x);
          }
      else if (numFirst >= numSecond)
          {
              for (int y = numFirst ; y != numSecond ; y--)
                  if (y % numDivisible == 0)
                      System.out.println(y);
         }
       }
    }
```

In the last "else if" When ever I enter 21 and -7 and have the divisiable be 7 it would always print out
    21
    14
    7
    0.
What I want it only 14 7 and 0.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this code:

```
while (numDivisible == 0)
{
    System.out.println("You cannot divide by 0, Please try again. ");
    numDivisible  =  kb.nextInt();
}
```

you should rewrite your loops.

I suggest you swap `numFirst` and `numSecond` instead of writing 2 loops (unless you do this to reverse the order of printing):

```
if (numSecond < numFirst)
{
    int temp = numFirst; numFirst = numSecond; numSecond = temp;
}
```

#### A simple change is to add a +1 to x at the start of the loop:

```
for (int x = numFirst+1  ; x != numSecond ; x++)
                  if (x % numDivisible == 0)
                    System.out.println(x);
```

#### For a more efficient solution, try:

```
// find smallest value > x which is divisible by numDivisible
int x = (numFirst/numDivisible+1)*numDivisible;
```

Then jump by numDivisible in your loop:

```
for (int x = (numFirst/numDivisible+1)*numDivisible; x < numSecond ; x+=numDivisible)
                    System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Begin your `for` loop at `numFirst-1`.

```
for (int y = numFirst - 1 ; y != numSecond ; y--)
```

Second option would be to add a test to your if, but not a fan:

```
if (y % numDivisible == 0 && y != numFirst)
```

Answer (score 1):

This resolves the problem:

```
import java.util.*;
public class numbers {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
        int n1 = kb.nextInt();
        int n2 = kb.nextInt();

        int a = n1 >= n2 ? n2 : n1;
        int b = n1 >= n2 ? n1 : n2;

        System.out.println("\nThis program will generate numbers BETWEEN\n" + a + " and " + b + " that are divisible by a certain number.");

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by: ");
        int divisor = kb.nextInt();
        while (divisor == 0) {
           System.out.println("You cannot divide by 0, Please try again. ");
           divisor =  kb.nextInt();
        }

        for (int n = a + divisor; n < b; n += divisor) {
            if (n % divisor == 0) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```